# Comparing two char multidimension arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, char, compare

I have two char arrays (both [10][10]) and I want to compare each element in first array with the same element in the other one and return 1 if they are similar.
Arrays:

```
char task [10][10] = {
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', t,' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ',t, ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, t, t, t,t, t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, t, t, t,t, t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
};

char solution [10][10] = {
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', t, t,' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ',t, ' ', ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, t, t, t,t, t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', t, t, t, t,t, t, ' ', ' ' },
{ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' },
};
```

Where t: char t = -2; (filed square)
I was trying sth like that:

```
bool cond (char task[10][10], char solution[10][10])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(task[i][j], solution[i][j]))
    }
}
}
```

and in main:

```
do
{
XxX(zadanie);
wpisz(kolor,w1,w2,zadanie,t);
}
while (!cond(task,solution));
cout << "Solved";
```

but it didn't work, there is some problem with conversion from char to *char and I have no more idea how to fix it. Probably it's obvious for people who code a lot, but I'm not one of them..

Comment: Your function return type is `bool`, but it is returning nothing.

Comment: You don't compare individual characters with `strcmp`, just use `==`.  `if (task[i][j] == solution [i][j])`.  Edit: Sorry, was just copying your original by mistake!

Comment: Trying it as well, but still don't work properly so I wasn't sure if this way of comparing two char is correct. If it's I'll keep looking for a logical mistake in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@skarpet
Your answer will overwrite result on every iteration. Try something like this:

```
bool warunek (char task[10][10], char solution[10][10])
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (task[i][j] != solution [i][j])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Additionally you dont have to iterate to the end, because it stops at the first missmatch.

Answer (score 0):

@GoodDeeds
@GoodDeeds
Right, I pasted wrong code:

```
bool warunek (char task[10][10], char solution[10][10])
{
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        if (task[i][j] == solution [i][j])
        {
            result= 0;
        } else
        {
            result= 1;
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```

Is that correct (I mean the code, not the logic, is it working as intended)?

Comment: It only checks the last char [9][9] in your arrays, because "result" will be overwritten on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard algorithms wherever possible (which means always):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>


bool matches_solution(char (&candidate)[10][10], char (&solution)[10][10])
{
  auto row_same = [](char (&l)[10], char (&r)[10])
  {
    return std::equal(std::begin(l), std::end(l),
                      std::begin(r));
  };

  return std::equal(std::begin(candidate), std::end(candidate),
                    std::begin(solution), row_same);
}
```